# Solving the Diffusion Equation for Strip CW Illumination

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, physics, fourier-transform

I've got this type of diffusion equation below in semi-infinite slab (used for biomedical optics):

$\mu_a\phi(y,z)-D\nabla^2\phi(y,z)=\delta(y)\delta(z)$

$z\in[0,\infty), y\in(-\infty,\infty), \phi<\infty$

EDIT:

I've used the next Fourier Transform:

$\psi(\bar k)=\int\phi(\bar r)exp(-i\bar k \cdot\bar r)d\bar r$

$\phi(\bar r)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int\psi(\bar k)exp(i\bar k \cdot\bar r)d\bar k$

and obtained:
$\psi(\bar k)=\frac{1}{\mu_a}\cdot(1-\frac{k_y^2+k_z^2}{\mu_{eff}^2})^{-1}$

I'm having troubles with performing the inverse transform and would love to get some help with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain what your domain and boundary conditions look like?

Comment: Thanks for your notice, @Dmoreno I've added the domain of the solution and some boundary conditions.

Comment: I've edited the question and showed a new approach for the solution using Fourier transform.

Comment: Use polar coordinates $k_y = k \cos \phi, k_z= k \sin \phi$, integral w.r.t. $\phi$ will be a Bessel function, then you will be left with a Bessel/rational function combination, which I believe has exact solution (look it up in Gradstein-Ryzhyk)